# Benchmarks for server response time

Tags: networking, performance, http, page-speed

[I was testing my website’s performance on Google Page Speed and it mentioned the response time at](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjane.cucumbertown.com%2Ffish-in-coconut-gravy-fish-recipe-dish&tab=desktop)

[image]
It average between .6-.8 seconds.

What’s the optimal server response time that’s acceptable? Is there any data or study done on the top performers related to this?

**Edit:**
There was a bit of confusion with the way I phrased the question.

To clarify, I am not talking about page load, but time taken for the browser to receive a KB or MB or data from the server. 
When pagespeed says that .6 seconds is slow, there is a benchmark they are referring to. Unfortunately I couldn’t get hold of that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is **no universal answer for this**.

`What’s a good server response time?` It is the time your users are ready to wait without disturbing their daily job.

As it seems you are talking about a public Website and not a private Web App, some studies have been published :

> 47% of people expect a web page to load in two seconds or less.
>
> 40% will abandon a web page if it takes more than three seconds to load.

You could find further reference in here :

- https://econsultancy.com/blog/10936-site-speed-case-studies-tips-and-tools-for-improving-your-conversion-rate/
- https://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/

Basically, Internet users, or Web Apps users, are impatient : this is human nature. More speed, more gain ! Why do you think ISPs are on the course to provide more and more speed ?

Comment: I would also add that websites that load progressively, and quickly show the parts of the website that have loaded so far, give the user a sense that the website is actually loading and they can begin to see what it will be, sooner than websites that pretty much appear all at once after most stuff is loaded, as those tend to have long wait times before the user can determine if they want to actually see the whole page. Try artificially reducing your bandwidth and increasing your latency to see what your page looks like to people with slow/congested internet.

Comment: Thanks for this. When pagespeed remarks that .56 seconds is slow then obviously there is a benchmark. Also this is server response time and not domReady. I would assume there would be some benchmark for response time per KB or MB.